# How much is a "scoop" of vanilla sugar?

Tags: measurements

I've seen a lot of recipes that call for a "scoop" of vanilla sugar. I know that this refers to the little scoop that comes with most vanilla sugar containers. However, I live in a country that sells vanilla sugar in little paper packets... How much is a "scoop" of vanilla sugar in tea- or tablespoons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up measuring the scoop spoon the next time I was in the US, and it turned out to be 1 Tablespoon.

Comment: I've lived in the US my whole life, in two very different states on opposite sides of the country, and never in my life have I encountered a creature I would characterize as a "vanilla sugar container" nor a "vanilla sugar scoop".

Answer (score 3):

Some recipes will note 1 scoop of vanilla sugar is required and also somewhere else mention the measurement to be 1 serving size. So for example, 1 Serving of Vanilla sugar would generally be two Tablespoons as seen in the recipe below from [here](http://www.culinaryschooljunky.com/2010/09/pancakes.html) :

"...a little whole wheat flour, a scoop of vanilla sugar, a bit of baking powder, and a pinch of salt."

**Pancakes**

- 2 c whole wheat flour
- 1 1/2 t baking powder
- 2 T sugar (I put my vanilla pods in mine so it infuses the sugar, but regular granulated will work fine)
  pinch of salt
- 1/4 c sour cream
- 1/4 c chai concentrate (Not a sweet one!)
- 1 egg

enough milk, coconut water or milk substitute until desired consistency
oil or butter for the pan

**To Garnish**

sliced strawberries (enough for pancakes and to garnish) 
1/4 c sour cream + sugar (I used rose) to taste
brandy syrup (boil 1/2 c sugar, 1/2 c water until dissolved, add 1/2 c brandy, cook 5 min to cook out harsh alcohol flavor)

Although this may vary from one recipe to another, I would recommend if the measurement is not explicitly provided looking for other recipes for similar dishes which call for the same ingredient.  Reasoning for this would be since it is not outlined, it is probably meant to be considered the common measurement of that ingredient.